# Поиск элементов в блоке

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как скриптом проверить, если у `<li>` есть див `sub` то `<li`> присвоить класс parent?

```
<ul class="nav">
<li><a style="background-image:url(assets/images/ico-buket.png)"> Букеты</a>
   <div class="sub">
      <a href="roznichnyij-magazin/mini-sadyi/rozyi-poshtuchno"> Розы поштучно</a>
      <a href="roznichnyij-magazin/mini-sadyi/buketyi-iz-roz"> Букеты из роз</a>
   </div>
</li>
<li><a style="background-image:url(assets/images/ico-autor.png)"> Авторские букеты</a></li>
<li><a style="background-image:url(assets/images/ico-rose.png)"> Розы</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$("li").each(function() {
  if ($(this).find("div.sub").length) {
    $(this).addClass("parent");
  }
});
```

```css
.parent, .parent a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a style="background-image:url(assets/images/ico-buket.png)"> Букеты</a>
    <div class="sub">
      <a href="roznichnyij-magazin/mini-sadyi/rozyi-poshtuchno"> Розы поштучно</a>
      <a href="roznichnyij-magazin/mini-sadyi/buketyi-iz-roz"> Букеты из роз</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a style="background-image:url(assets/images/ico-autor.png)"> Авторские букеты</a></li>
  <li><a style="background-image:url(assets/images/ico-rose.png)"> Розы</a></li>
</ul>
```

или

```js
$("li:has(div.sub)").addClass("parent");
```

```css
.parent, .parent a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a style="background-image:url(assets/images/ico-buket.png)"> Букеты</a>
    <div class="sub">
      <a href="roznichnyij-magazin/mini-sadyi/rozyi-poshtuchno"> Розы поштучно</a>
      <a href="roznichnyij-magazin/mini-sadyi/buketyi-iz-roz"> Букеты из роз</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a style="background-image:url(assets/images/ico-autor.png)"> Авторские букеты</a></li>
  <li><a style="background-image:url(assets/images/ico-rose.png)"> Розы</a></li>
</ul>
```